# Auto ID in Android Firebase SDK?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does the [childByAutoId](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/childByAutoId) functionality, available in Firebase iOS SDK, exist in Android?

Basically in iOS I'm creating that id like:

```
let key = getAddPlayersQueueRef().child("tasks").childByAutoId().key;
addPlayersQueueRef?.child(byAppendingPath: "tasks/\(key!)").setValue(task);
```

Which produces a key like `-KYJqaljjDG0Vp2L_cW5`.

Can I do that on Android? I don't see any similar method on the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Android (and JavaScript) that method is called `push()`.

You can easily see this when you compare the documentation on adding items to lists between [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).